# How to sort this array by type (dir first and then files)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, file-type, alphabetical

I wanna know how to sort arrays like this:

```
$array[] = Array (
    'name' => '/home/gtsvetan/public_html/presta/cms.php'
    'type' => 'text/x-php'
    'size' => 1128
    'lastmod'  => 1339984800
);
$array[] = Array (
    'name' => '/home/gtsvetan/public_html/presta/docs/'
    'type' => 'dir'
    'size' => 0
    'lastmod' => 1329253246
);
```

I wanna to sort it first by type (folders first and then files) and then alphabetical. But I don't know how to sort it.

Best regards,
George!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

In compare function you do two comparisions on name & type - something like below:

```
function compare_f($a,$b) {

 if($a['type']=='dir'&&$b['type']!='dir') return 1;
 if($a['type']!='dir'&&$b['type']=='dir') return -1;
 if(substr($a['name'],-1,1)=='/') $a['name']=substr($a['name'],0,-1);
 if(substr($b['name'],-1,1)=='/') $b['name']=substr($b['name'],0,-1);
 $af_array=explode('/',$a['name']);
 $a_name=$af_array[count($af_array)-1];
 $bf_array=explode('/',$b['name']);
 $b_name=$bf_array[count($bf_array)-1];

 if($a_name>$b_name) 
    return 1;
  return -1;

}

usort($array,'compare_f');
```

Comment: To work properly for me it must be like that: `if($a['type']=='dir' && $b['type']!='dir') return -1;
  if($a['type']!='dir' && $b['type']=='dir') return 1;` but thanks because I can seen a good explanation for this function!

Comment: this will only show dirs first. later results will not be alphabetical

Comment: At the moment I test it and it shows dirs first alphabetical then files also alphabetical...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

```
$dir = array();
$file = array();

$dir = array();
$file = array();

foreach($array as $b=>$v) {
if($v['type'] == "dir") {
    $dir[] = $v;
} else {
    $file[] = $v;
}
}

$combined = array_merge($dir, $file);
```

Feel free to adjust it.

Comment: Where is the sorting happening?